# Issue happens when installing Django on Windows 7

Tags: python, django, installation

I've got an issue when installing Django.

The official guide says open cmd with administrator privileges and run "setup.py install"

I did this but then the system default python editor came out, I don't know how to do anymore, please  help me~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that the py extension is linked with the editor rather than the Python interpreter.

Right-click on a py file and click "Open with" then select the default program and choose 'C:...\Python2x\python.exe'

That should fix the pb

Comment: Or, just type `python setup.py install`.

Comment: Yes! This is the easier way to fix the pb but I think that the association of py files with an editor can be a little annoying. I recommend to fix it too.